# barman + how to cleanup the wals folder

Tags: postgresql, linux, barman

we are using the **barman** - backup and restore for postgresql

we noticed the under folder usage  - `/var/lib/barman/main-db-server/wals` is **110G**

example to what we have

```
824M    /var/lib/barman/main-db-server/wals/0000000100000010
692M    /var/lib/barman/main-db-server/wals/0000000100000011
677M    /var/lib/barman/main-db-server/wals/0000000100000012
681M    /var/lib/barman/main-db-server/wals/0000000100000013
677M    /var/lib/barman/main-db-server/wals/0000000100000014
686M    /var/lib/barman/main-db-server/wals/0000000100000015
680M    /var/lib/barman/main-db-server/wals/0000000100000016
701M    /var/lib/barman/main-db-server/wals/0000000100000017
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

and date and time

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Nov 15  2019 0000000100000010
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Nov 18  2019 0000000100000011
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Nov 21  2019 0000000100000012
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Nov 25  2019 0000000100000013
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Nov 28  2019 0000000100000014
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Dec  2  2019 0000000100000015
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Dec  6  2019 0000000100000016
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Dec 11  2019 0000000100000017
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Dec 15  2019 0000000100000018
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Dec 19  2019 0000000100000019
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Dec 23  2019 000000010000001A
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Dec 27  2019 000000010000001B
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Dec 31  2019 000000010000001C
drwxr-xr-x. 2 barman barman   12288 Jan  5  2020 000000010000001D
.
.
.
.
```

in our case we cant accepted **wals** folder with 110G because the disk is 150G  and disk is reached 99%

any tuning or configuration to purge the folders in wals ? maybe in `barman.conf`?

Comment: Aren't they removed as soon as you take a full backup? What is your retention period for backups?

Answer (score 1):

The files from "wals/" are automatically removed when the backups they support are deleted.  Delete all backups that are older than your retention policy dictates must be kept, and the "wals" will go away on their own.

WAL files generally compress extremely well.  You can turn on compression in barman.conf, although getting this to apply retroactively might be tricky.

Comment: can you please descibe how to configure the retention policy

Comment: second - not understand why WALS not deleted and what we need to do about this

Comment: You can manually use `barman delete` to remove old backups, or use `retention_policy` as described in the docs (http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.12/).